# Java - Base64 byte array return as a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, base64

We have a supplier that we send a service call to, and they generate a PDF document and return it to us as a Base64 encoded string.
We then need to grab this value exactly as it is, and send it to a secondary service that sends an email with the PDF attached.

The problem is the WSDL that they sent us for the first service defines the return field as a byte array, and i can't seem to find a way of using the exact value as a string.

Is there a way to take the exact value in the field and return it as a string value without attempting a conversion to readable text?

Sample string (I obviously can't attached the PDF encoded string, as it is huge):

```
<ifx:BinData>QmFzZTY0U3RyaW5n</ifx:BinData> //This is the value "Base64String" encoded as base64.
```

Expected output:

A string variable with a value of "QmFzZTY0U3RyaW5n".

Every which way I've tried results in me getting a string back with the decoded value: "Base64String".

I have tried the following:

`Arrays.toString(inputField)`

`Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(inputField) //This double encoded my field`.

`Looping through byte array and converting to string`

`new String(inputField)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have your tried [new String( inputField )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) ?

Comment: I have yes, i forgot to add it above (Ive tried so many things already I've forgotten a couple :) )

Comment: If that did not work, the data may not be encoded with the java default charset. You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset- . But you need to find out which charset is being used.

Comment: if i manually copy and paste it out it works perfectly.
the problem i found is that as soon as i try convert it from the byteArray it tries to translate the byte values to normal values, which is not ideal as a PDF document contains alot of non-unicode characters when its opened like that

Comment: Base64 is ASCII and as such a subset of most character sets. `new String(inputField, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)` should have worked. Fildor's code should have worked too, using some default charset. Unless you are on an AS/400 mainframe with EBCDIC.

Comment: if new `String(inputField)` does not give you the correct base64 string, you may try with encoding specification `new String(inputField, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())`, you need to know the correct encoding for the string.

Comment: "contains alot of non-unicode characters" - that doesn't matter. It's bytes encoded in base64 and thereof the byte-representation. As Joop sais, if you decode that byterepresentation with ASCII, you should get a string that is the Base64-encoded *bytes* of the PDF.

Comment: _Question to make sure:_ Bytes were Base64 encoded, and delivered as `byte[]`. This byte array you want as String - not the original bytes, no Base64 decoding?

Comment: @JoopEggen That's what I  infered from "Expected output:
A string variable with a value of "QmFzZTY0U3RyaW5n"." - but you are right, we should make that crystal clear.

Comment: i need a string output of the base64 encoded string. visually it should look the same as what is in the return field (Which is base64 encoded)

Comment: i tried using StandardCharsets.US_ASCII and the results were the same.
The return is still the decoded byte array value (A string value of "Base64String")

Comment: Then it is automatically Base64 decoded. `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(inputField)`

Comment: i also tried that, and then the final string is a double base64 encoded string. So i decode it, and get another string, then decode it and get my pdf.